# change value in dropdown menu sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have a dropdown box name `Status` added in sharepoint page which have option (`choose`.. , `In progress`, `Closed`). Where `Choose..` is bydefault value. When I open the page the value `Choose..` should get change automatically to `In progress`.

Like if dropdown status == Choose
value should get change to In progress while page load.
Can someone provide me javascript to perform this action.

**What I have tried:**

```
<script src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if($('#drStatus').find("option:selected").val() == "Choose..") { 
        $('#drStatus').val("In Progress"); 
    } 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: what is your SharePoint page? Is it a custom application page or a custom web part built in Visual Studio or else? Please add more details and tags to your question also the SharePoint version (2010 or 2013) :)

Comment: This is custom webpart created in visual studio

Comment: <script src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('#drStatus').find("option:selected").val() == "Choose..")
{
    $('#drStatus').val("In Progress");
}
});
</script>

But this is not working now

Comment: How are you creating the dropdown in Visual Studio? Is it an ASP DropDownList?

Comment: dropdown is created in webpart user control and taking data from database

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($("select[title='_title of column_'] option:selected").val() == "Choose.."){
$("select[title='_title of column_']").val("In progress...");
}
});
```

not tested, but something like that should do it

Comment: Fixed your quotes

Comment: And just a note, if this is SP2013/SPO, if the field is a required field, then the title would be `_title of column_ Required Field`.

Comment: This is not working.. just one question field display name is "Status" and ID is drstatus which I have to use in Title. Thanks

Comment: Hi user21081... look at your sourcecode with developer tools (F12)... you can see the title attribute there...

Comment: @user21081 What code did you use that did not work? And what version of SP are you on?

Comment: this working on all sharepoint versions... I'm working on SP2013 onprem... but maybe you are not implementing jquery? see here:  https://jquery.com/

Comment: @domsen123 The dropdown is in a web part, created via Visual Studio.  I have a feeling the dropdown is a .Net DropDownList, and OP is getting the id wrong, since the id changes when the HTML is generated.

Comment: i have checked using F12 and ID showing is ctl00$m$g_b3b4524e_b014_41c4_a818_77a3eaedc972$drpInitiativeType

Comment: i am using code...

<script src="/sites/BM/Documents/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('#drStatus').find("option:selected").val() == "<Initiative Type>")
{
    $('#drStatus').val("FRP");
}
});
</script>

Comment: maybe you can add a title attribute in visual studio to asp dropdown? or an CssClass... something you can select by jQuery...

Comment: @user21081 try `$('input[id*=drpInitiativeType]')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($("select[title='Status']").find("option:selected").val() == "Choose..")
{
    $("select[title='Status']").val("InProgress");
}
});
```

Comment: This is not working.. just one question field display name is "Status" and ID is drstatus which I have to use in Title. Thanks

Comment: If drstatus is your dropdown ID then then                                                                                                          You can Use $("#drstatus") as a selector instead of $("select[title='Status']") in above answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented a custom web part then why not set your drop-down value through your C#/VB.net code?

I will give you an example of a C# code on how you can change the default value in a drop-down list on page load event. In below code "status" is your drop-down list name.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = status.SelectedValue.ToString();
    if(selectedValue == "Choose")
    {
       //This is very simple but will result in an error if the dropdown already has a 
       status.SelectedValue == "In Progress"

       or
       //add any of below code which should not result in an error in case there already is a selected item. 

       //add error checking, just an example, FindByValue may return null
       status.Items.FindByValue("Yourvalue").Selected = true;

       or
       //add error checking, just an example, FindByText may return null
       status.Items.FindByText("In Progress").Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If an asp.net control is used inside some content area in a webpart, I guess while rendering ID will get changed. 
So the proposed solution can be, Give your dropdown a unique class name

Assumed **mark-up** is below

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drStatus" runat="server" CssClass="UniqueClassName">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Choose" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="In Progess" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Closed" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
//set which text you want find
var textToFind = 'In Progress';

$(".UniqueClassName > option").each(function() {
    if (this.text === textToFind) {
        $(this).prop('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this too.  You can do something like this:

```
$('select[title="Origin State"] option:contains("GA")').prop({ selected: true });
```

Be wary of the contains you may need eq depending on the content of your list.  (GAP contains GA).  I only posted with the contains because I have it verified in extant code.